# How to find the nth Term in tsql

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table as under

```
Term
0
8
24
48
80
X
```

The desired output being

```
Term1        Term2             Diff

0               8               8

8              24               16

24             48               24

48             80               32

80             x                40
```

I have the below script

```
Declare @t Table(Term varchar(10))
Insert Into @t 
Select '0' Union All
Select '8' Union All
Select '24' Union All
Select '48' Union All
Select '80' Union All
Select 'X'
```

So far I have tried as

```
;With Cte1 As
(
    Select rn = ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order By (select 1)),* From @t
)
,cte2 as(
Select 
    Term1 = (Select term from Cte1 where rn=1)
    ,Term2 = (Select term from Cte1 where rn=2)
    ,Diff = Cast((Select term from Cte1 where rn=2) as int) - Cast((Select term from Cte1 where rn=1) as int)
)


Select * from cte2
```

I donot know what to do in the recursive part of cte2..

Help needed

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure why the difference between `80` and `x` is supposed to be 40, but you can handle that by tweaking the CTE to return what you need for the last row.

```
;WITH Cte1 AS
(
  SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)), * FROM @t
)
SELECT
  Term1 = Cte1.Term,
  Term2 = (SELECT Term FROM Cte1 AS a_CTE where a_CTE.rn = Cte1.rn + 1),
  Diff = CAST((SELECT CASE Term WHEN 'X' THEN 120 ELSE Term END
               FROM Cte1 AS a_CTE
               WHERE a_CTE.rn = Cte1.rn + 1) AS int)
         - CAST(Cte1.Term AS int)
FROM Cte1
WHERE ISNUMERIC(Cte1.Term) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using PIVOT and not a recursive CTE. Cf.: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx